# How do you make custom named appear like regular items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to custom name items with anvils and commands, but have the names not be in italic.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Survival, only with commands.